# How to automatically assign a color to the maximum and minimum values in a set of selected cells in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have some heterogeneous friction measurements that I want to analyze:

[image]

I want to adjust the colors of maximum and minimum on a set of cells. For example, I want the `MAX(C16,E16,G16,J16,L16,N16)` to become automatically red and `MIN(C16,E16,G16,J16,L16,N16)` to become green, and so on for other rows. I would appreciate it if you could help me know if there is a built-in functionality in Excel to do so, or maybe I can have a macro (e.g., VB or Python) to do this.

Answer (score 0):

See Conditional Formatting, found either in Format menu: Conditional Formatting or the Conditional Formatting button on the Home tab:

[image]

And, using Top and Bottom:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Click Conditional Formatting
2. Click on New Rule
3. [Search 'Format value top or bottom ranked'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWEpq.png)

4. Then click 'Format'
5. Go to the tab Font and change the color